# How to create a Silverlight unit test using TableServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows Phone 7 application using [Azure Toolkit](http://watoolkitwp7.codeplex.com/). I also create unit tests for it using [NUnit Test Runner for WP7](http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/documentation).

Now, I want to test a code, that saves data to azure table using TableServiceContext.BeginSaveChanges method (there is no synchronous SaveChanges method available).

I need to call BeginSaveChanges and wait until it finishes in the same test method, like this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    ICloudClientFactory factory = new CloudClientFactory();
    ITableServiceContext context = factory.ResolveTableServiceContext("MyTable");
    // add some entries here
    UpdateContext(context);

    AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResentEvent(false);
    context.BeginSaveChanges((IAsyncResult result) =>
    {
        context.EndSaveChanges(result);
        autoResetEvent.Set();
    }, null);

    bool set = autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    if (set)
    {
       Assert.Pass();
    }
    else
    {
       Assert.Fail();
    }   
}
```

**autoResetEvent.WaitOne()** returns only when 5-sec timeout is expired, and only after that the async callback for **context.BeginSaveChanges** is called.
Why is that?

I also tried calling **context.BeginSaveChanges** on a thread from the ThreadPool (using **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem** method) - but that didn't help.

Does this behavior have anything to do with Windows Phone 7/Silverlight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both ICloudClientFactory and ITableServiceContext are interfaces.  Instead of going directly to actual Azure cloud objects use mocking.  This will remove outside dependencies - which shouldn't be there for unit-tests anyway - and allow you to test your code in isolation.

So:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<ITableServiceContext>()
ITableServiceContext context=mockContext.Object
```

Here's a link to the Moq Quickstart: http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

Comment: Thanks for your help! Well, I obviously used the wrong word, that's not really a unit test I was going to create, but rather an integration test. I will consider mocking my dependencies and writing some unit tests, but I also wanted to get my integration tests working..

Comment: I think the root of my problem was blocking of the UI thread by the test. Somewhere deep inside in BeginContextSaveChanges there must be a call to UI thread, that does not get to execute. One solution might be using Silverlight Testing Framework I guess (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/asynchronous-testing/).

Comment: I ended up with custom workaround though. I have an object, let's call it TestHarnessState. So each test harness registers its tests there during setup (thState.RegisterTest("testX")). And in the callback each test of the harness calls thState.TestFinished("testX"). I updated the test runner to launch a timer that checks every second if all tests are finished (thState.AllTestsFinished) and only when they are finished shows the results page. That works fine for me.